# How to force Spring Boot reload to the configuration file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When I modify the `application-dev.yml` file, it will load the configuration file after the `Spring Boot` is started, otherwise it wille not reload the `appliation-dev.yml` file. My IDE is `IDEA`.

My question:

```
How to force `Spring Boot` reload to the configuration file?
```

PS:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Redeploy your app.  It'll pick it up.

Comment: @duffymo It's not, I stop it and redeploy, but it not reload

Comment: Shouldn't it be application.yml?  The dev part should be a profile that's inside.

Comment: WTF??? It works?? But , i didn't change anything.....

Comment: @duffymo Thank you, man.

Comment: If your configuration file is external to the project this might help you:https://stackoverflow.com/a/53787761/330070 - I've described an approach in another topic

Answer (score 0):

After you employ the spring cloud, you will be able to reload your configuration by posting to `/refresh` endpoint